# Running Mstest.exe without team foundation server.

Tags: visual-studio-2010, continuous-integration, mstest, azure-devops

I want to run tests in comman line using mstest.exe. Here is the command which I am trying to execute

```
MSTest.exe /platform:[x64] "/testcontainer:D:\Dev\tas\Tests.dll" /resultsfile:"D:\Dev\TestResults.xml"
```

But everytime I am getting error.

```
No Build Uri specified for publish operation.
```

For switch syntax, type "MSTest /help"

I am not using any teamFoundation server. How do I run this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `/platform` command line option is actually related to the publishing, not test execution (as described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489(v=vs.100).aspx).  When you specify at least one publishing option, MSTest validates that the minimum required set of publishing options have been supplied.

Since you don't really want to publish, simply getting rid of the `/platform` option should fix the problem.

Comment: If I dont use /platform is there any other way to mention that the dlls are 64 bit. without this option it executes for 32 bit build but fails for 64.

Comment: This can be done via test settings.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee782531(v=vs.100).aspx for details.